# Firefox execution fails from a root executed script with privilege drop

Tags: debian, sudo, firefox, users, permissions

I can't run firefox from a sudoed python script that drops privileges to normal user. If i write

```
# sudo python
>>> import os
>>> import pwd, grp
>>> uid = pwd.getpwnam('norby')[2]
>>> gid = grp.getgrnam('norby')[2]
>>> os.setegid(gid)
>>> os.seteuid(uid)
>>> import webbrowser
>>> webbrowser.get('firefox').open('www.google.it')
True
>>> # It returns true but doesn't work
>>> from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
>>> p = Popen('firefox www.google.it', shell=True,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
>>> # Doesn't execute the command
```

I think that is not a python problem, but firefox/iceweasel/debian configuration problem. Maybe firefox read only UID and not EUID, and doesn't execute process because UID is equal 0. What do you think about?

Comment: But why are you trying to write a python script to be ran as root to do this. What is the objective?

Comment: The script works with network in a low level layer, so it must run as root. I think there is nothing wrong to drop privileges in the right way, and then execute firefox. But it doesn't works.

Comment: Does Python's `Popen` work with gui programs? Perhaps the problem is not where you think it is.

Comment: Firefox will run as root, so the concern you have in the last part of your question isn't the issue.

Comment: Is it a problem if I cross post it on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to export environment variable named DISPLAY with value ':0.0'. That might make it work. Ask on stackoverflow if you don't know how to export environment variables using python.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is it can't access the display on the X server, is it running? I wouldn't recommend running firefox with root permissions, that'd be like running IE on a windows box.

You said in a comment that you was launching it in a lower run level. The error is because you're launching firefox in that lower level before X comes up with an active display. Delay it's running until X is up.

Comment: X server is running, and i'm not running firefox from root privilege, but i've dropped it to 'norby' normal user.

Comment: is it running at execution time?

Comment: sure! =) I'm not a linux newbie

Comment: Can the user launch it normally? Can you launch it with fakeroot?

Comment: Can you launch any windowed app with it, try something like gedit.

Comment: Yes, the user can launch it normally. I don't want to use other external tools (except su-like programs to start the whole python script)

Comment: @malfist: A command like 'sudo kwrite' works. I think the problem is about firefox that don't want to be executed from a user with UID==0 (also if EUID is >0

Comment: so change root's uid ;)

Comment: backup the system first, it might break a few things

Comment: Um, this should be interesting...

Comment: change root's uid? o.O I prefer to not waste my system =)

Comment: It might not, it might work fine. Or, it could blow up. You could script it to change roots uid at the start of the script and then change it back after firefox is launched ;)

Comment: @Malfist: I really hope that you are not serious. Changing root's uid in order to run a script (which may already have other problems) is an awful idea. Also, a commenter on the original question points out that Firefox _can_ (apparently) run as root. So this isn't even the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You really really shouldn't do this. Like, **really**.

Why are you trying to?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess, you'll have to specify an X-server. I'm afraid I have no idea how to actually *do* that in python though :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, you would normally want to use `gksu` or `gksudo` or `sux` to get root privileges for an X application. Second, why are you using `sudo` on Debian? (I mean is `sudo` even enabled? It's not by default on Debian, as opposed to Ubuntu or OS X.) Third, I can't think of any circumstance where you actually *need* to run a browser with root privileges.

There are cases when you need a gui application as root - say, you want to edit a system file (*/etc/network/interfaces* for example), and you're most comfortable editing with `gedit`. That's not an unreasonable thing to want to do. But you would want to use `gksu` or a similar utility to transfer the privileges.

Comment: yes, sudo is enabled, but no one is a sudoer

Comment: @Malfist: 6 of one; half-dozen of the other. I take your point, but since in fact many Debian users don't install the Desktop task at all, `sudo` is often not even installed. Nevertheless, I grant that if you install the Gnome (or KDE or XFCE, I suppose) packages, then `sudo` gets installed. It's still not the right tool to get gui privileges.

Comment: Sudo is installed in debian system. I have to execute a browser from a python script that must run as root. I'm only trying to drop privilege and run the browser. Nothing dangerous.

Comment: @Emilio: First, the whole Python script-which-must-be-root -> Firefox idea _still_ sounds like a bad idea. Second, are you sure that your regular user is in the `sudoers` file? Again, Debian is _not_ Ubuntu. Even if you run Gnome, I don't think that regular users are automatically added to the list of users who can run `sudo`. I believe that out of the box in Debian only root can.

Comment: Sudo is not the problem (the user will execute the program as he want, with sudo, gtksudo, kdesudo, etc.), but the problem is that the browser don't works even if i drop privileges in the right way..

Comment: sudo is installed without the a windowing system. The Debian box I've been working on is a server and it doesn't have X.

Comment: @Malfist: I'm not sure what it's a dependency of then. If you install Debian selecting _only_ the Standard task from the Tasksel menu in the installer, `sudo` is not installed. See here for the list of packages in the Standard task. When I run `aptitude why sudo`, I can track back and see that the only reason I have it installed is that I installed `pcmanfm`, which recommends `gksu` which requires `sudo`.

Comment: Is not a sudo problem =) I want only to execute firefox after dropping privileges.

Comment: Oops: I forgot the link to the list of packages: http://wiki.debian.org/tasksel

Comment: @Emilio: that's fine, but now I'm in a debate because "someone is _wrong_ on the internet." http://xkcd.com/386/

Comment: @Tele: ahahha ok =)

Answer (score 0):

I use sux.

1. apt-get installl sux
2. sux firefox

> Description: wrapper around su which will transfer your X credentials
>   Sux is a wrapper around the standard su command which will transfer
>   your X credentials to the target user.

Comment: I prefer to find a solution not based on what *su program is used, but to try to run firefox from the script executed by root, but with dropped privileges